# Why do I need to member-initialize a non-static array member in a constexpr class?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

The following code desperately needs `: values()` to compile, at least in ideone::C++14:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct Table
{
    constexpr Table() : values()
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            values[i] = i * i * i;
        }
    }
    int values[N];
};

int main() {
    constexpr auto a = Table<1000>();
    for (auto x : a.values)
        std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

But why? I had thoughts along "values could also be initialized in a non-constexpr way and values() does explicitly say that we initialize it in a constexpr-compliant manner". But is not omitting `: values()` just as clear?

Comment: `clang` gives a strange message: `assignment to object outside its lifetime is not allowed in a constant expression` for the `=` in the constructor of `Table` if I omit `values()`.

Comment: "for the constructor of a class or struct, every base class sub-object and every non-variant non-static data member must be initialized. "

Comment: But it is initialized anyways, just Not explicit in any case. It works for non-constexpr classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the semantics.

Omitting the member from the initialization list will perform default initialization, which in this case leaves the array with unspecified values. That negates the purpose of a `constexpr`.

Value initializing the array performs zero initialization on each array element (since this is an array of built in types).

Comment: this indeed makes sense and I did not know that

Comment: Still, why is it not allowed to initialize the elements in the for loop? Afterwards, all array elements have values

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, For simplicity of implementation, I think. Judging by the quote Serge put bellow, the committee may have thought the following the c'tor chain may be less intractable than tracking an arbitrary c'tor body.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because it is required by standard. Draft n4296 for current C++ standard states at :

7.1.5 The constexpr specifier [dcl.constexpr] §4 (emphasize mine):

> 4 The definition of a constexpr constructor shall satisfy the following constraints:
> ...
>
> In addition, either its function-body shall be = delete, or it shall satisfy the following constraints:
>
> (4.4) — either its function-body shall be = default, or the compound-statement of its function-body shall satisfy
> the constraints for a function-body of a constexpr function;
> (4.5) — **every non-variant non-static data member and base class sub-object shall be initialized** (12.6.2);
> ...

Comment: Perhaps the standard should clarify really that default initialization does not apply as "initialized". However, having an unspecified value really should preclude from being a `constexpr`, so I guess it follows logically.